# Linux Installation libX11-devel

Tags: linux, offline, yum, pkg-config

I am trying to build QT4 (porting from Redhat 5 to 7 with an upgraded gcc compiler) in RedHat 7 and I was getting an error saying `X11/Xlib.h` can't be found. Anyways, after doing some research most people said to install `libX11-devel` to get those x11 libraries. Since I am using an offline machine I can't do "apt-get" type commands and have to manually install RPMs. So, I went to my RH-7 installation DVD and got `"libX11-devel-1.6.3-3.el7.x86-64"` (I have 64 bit OS) and tried to install using `"yum install libX11-devel-1.6.3-3.el7.x86_64"` and I am getting dependencies errors. It's saying

```
...Requires: pkgconfig(kbproto)
...Required: pkgconfig(xcb)
...Requires: pkgconfig(xproto)
...Requires: pkgconfig(xcb) >= 1.1.92
```

So, here are my questions.

1) when it says `"pkgconfig(kbproto)"`, is it saying find the `"kbproto....RPM"` and do a `"yum install"`. In my dvd I only have `"xorg-x11-proto-devel-7.7.13.el7.noarch.rpm"`. Do I have to somehow find `"xorg-x11-proto......x86_64.rpm"` since it's a 64 bit machine?

2) Is there a difference between `"yum install"` and `pkgconfig "install"`? Are there any other installation variants in Linux?

3)For an offline machine, Is there anyway I can get all the dependencies and install everything at once ?

4) Why is it saying `"xcb"` requires twice. If I just get a `xcb...rpm` version above 1.1.92 can I just install it once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before actually answering the questions, I am going to suggest to see if you can get the latest version of the packages. The packages on the installation DVD may be really out of date and contain known vulernabilities, and other bugs. Can you use `yumdownloader` - in an online environment - to download the latest version onto a separate DVD and use that as the installation source? See https://access.redhat.com/solutions/10154 for more information.

To answer the questions themselves:

1. `Requires: foo` can refer to a package `foo` or a "feature" `foo`. `pkgconfig(kbproto)` is a "feature" (or virtual requires). You can use `yum`/`rpm` to see what provides this. On my Fedora box, for example, `rpm -q --provides xorg-x11-proto-devel` shows that this package indeed provides `pkgconfig(kbproto)`.

   As for `x86_64` vs `noarch`, it doesn't matter. `noarch` packages work everywhere. Other packages are restricted to the platform. So `x86_64` only works on intel/amd x86 64-bit machines. Installing `noarch` should be fine in your case. If you only had a `i686` package, though, that wouldn't be sufficient. You would have to find a `x86_64` or `noarch` package.
2. Yes, there's a big difference between `yum` and `pkg-config`. They do *completely* different things. One is a system tool for installing RPM packages. The other is a tool for developers for using the right headers and compiler flags. If your concern is finding/installing RPMs, do not use `pkg-config` directly.
3. Do you have access to an online machine that can access the RHEL 7 yum repositories? On that machine, do something like this:

```
    mkdir rhel7-packages
    cd rhel7-packages
    yum provides '*/X11/Xlib.h'    # make a note of the package that provides this file. it's libX11-devel on Fedora here
    yumdownloader --resolve libX11-devel   # download libX11-devel and all dependencies not installed on the system
```

Then copy/install the RPMs on the machine without internet access.

4. It's probably printing out `xcb` twice because it's two different requirements. The unversioned requirement will be satisfied if you install any verison of xcb. The versioned requirement will only be satisfied if you install 1.1.92. If you install 1.1.92, it will satisified both the requirements.

Comment: Thank you very much. It did work. Essentially, I had to find the RPMs that have the pkgconfig(xcb) and pkgconfig(kbproto) and install it. "XCB" rpm had another dependency on "xau" and I had to install that as well.

Answer (score 1):

1.
You have to resolve the dependency on the system where you are building your package. This means you need to have those dependencies installed, inclusing `libX11-devel`. To do that, download the RPMs manually from EL7 repos to local disk and run this:

```
$ mkdir -p /tmp/libX11_dep_rpms && cd /tmp/libX11_dep_rpms

# Download all dependencies from here. All your packages should be available here:
# http://mirror.centos.org/centos-7/7/os/x86_64/Packages/
# Then install
$ yum localinstall *.rpm

# After this you should be able to build your qt4 package, provided all dependencies are resolved. Otherwise, repeat the procedure for all dependencies
# If you can't download packages, then you need to create a FULL DVD ISO that will contain all packages.
```

2.
`pkgconfig` ensures that a requirement is coming from a particular build that provides a particular version of the library. [Here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/PackagingDrafts/PkgConfigBuildRequires) are some detail.

3.
Get the [Everything ISO](http://isoredirect.centos.org/centos/7/isos/x86_64/CentOS-7-x86_64-Everything-1804.iso) from EL7.

4.
This has to do with the `pkgconfig` and library versions.